# Is there any difference in codes which are used for phones with default NFC and the phone with NFC enabled micro SD card?

Tags: android, nfc, android-library

I am developing an app based on NFC. But the app will be developed for phones which basically do not have NFC but NFC is enabled in them using NFC enabled micro SD card. Is there any difference in codes which are used for phones with default NFC and the phone with NFC enabled micro SD card?  Any one please help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as your device is supporting the Micro SD NFC cards using the inbuilt APIs, there should be no change in the code you have to write.

However, if the Micro SD NFC support is from the OEM or some third party ROMs, you may have to utilize SDKs provided by them, for which you should contact them directly.